# Set different text to the same id divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have 3 divs with the same id and i need set values for them. The divs are generated dynamically and i want to set values.

```
<div id='product_0'>
<div id='product_name'>Product 1
</div>
</div>
<div id='product_1'>
<div id='product_name'>Product 2
</div>
</div>
<div id='product_2'>
<div id='product_name'>Product 3
</div>
</div>
```

The generated divs have default text and i want to change through jquery or javascript. Can anyone help me in this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: Should there be an event on which the values are changed?

Comment: i have three values which i can set on page load

Comment: You should use unique ids

Comment: well this is the problem, the divs are generated dynamically . I have parent  div which is unique product_1, product_2, product_3

Comment: SO you wanna set some text when they are being generated?

Comment: yes when they are generated then i can write an external script to set my values but cant figure out how to set a text

Comment: First of all: Setting the same ID to multiple elements on a page is invalid (as mentioned). But what keeps you from targeting classes? That works with js jQuery as well. just give them a class called "js-product-name" for example and youre free to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try like this using parent `div` id

```
 $("div#product_0").children("div").text("Product 4");
 $("div#product_1").children("div").text("Product 5");
 $("div#product_2").children("div").text("Product 6");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are in wrong way. Dont use same id . Use Class.

Html:

```
<div id='product_0'>
    <div id='product_name0' class="product">Product 1</div>
</div>
<div id='product_1'>
    <div id='product_name1' class="product">Product 2</div>
</div>
<div id='product_2'>
    <div id='product_name2' class="product">Product 3</div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$("div .product").eq(0).text("Product 4");
$("div .product").eq(1).text("Product 5");
$("div .product").eq(2).text("Product 6");
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shree/0yj4azec/)

Comment: thanks for the answer, as i said earlier i dont have any control on the divs they are generated DYNAMICALLY.

Comment: When generate dynamic div give class not a id  and in for each loop in class catch index and set value.

Comment: its not generated by me. I am working a company and we have HTML5 AD builder which is generating everything.

Comment: Well slap their ad company for creating invalid html by using id's that duplicate. All id's should be unique...

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with some of the other answers in that IDs should be unique, you can still target these elements by simply adding the tag to your selector, like so:

```
<div id='testing'></div>
<div id='testing'></div>
<div id='testing'></div>

<script>
alert($('div#testing').length);
</script>
```

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/st9pz3qo/